# ubuntu 13.10 no option to install to usb

Tags: installation, usb, 13.10

do not want to dual boot or clean install on pc.  want usb boot option.  downloaded ISO image but installer does not start or offer usb install option   suggestions?

Comment: download unetbootin software,and make bootable usb through that,And change te boot order to usb in bios.

Answer (score 0):

Just download lili (Linux Live USB creator).It helps to make bootable usb of ubuntu.After crating bootable ubuntu usb boot the computer,select usb asthe boot device from bios.When it boots from usb you will have two options either install or try ubuntu.If you don't want to install ubuntu you can select try ubuntu option.Then you can use ubuntu from usb

Answer (score 0):

If you are having windows then use Universal-Usb-Installer to create bootable usb stick, and make sure its does not show any error.

If you are having Ubuntu then search is dash for Stratup disk creator and follow the [steps here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

After making Bootable Usb Stick go to Bios and change its First Boot Priority to usb , and save it ..do restart and it will boot from USB.